# Filter aggregation in a nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

With this query, I identify the most used categories. I want to get the number of the categories that I have identified with the sentiment value greater than 0.

```
[
    'aggs' => [
        'category_sentiment' => [
            [
                'nested' => [
                    'path' => 'entities.categories'
                ],
                'aggs' => [
                    'buckets' => [
                        'terms' => [
                            'field' => 'entities.categories.category',
                            'size' => 100
                        ],
                        'aggs' => [
                            'pos' => [
                                'filter' => [
                                    'range' => [
                                        'sentiment_score' => [ 'gt' => 0 ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The result i got

```
            "category_sentiment": {
                "doc_count": 8424,
                "buckets": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "Category 1",
                            "doc_count": 6614,
                            "pos": {
                                "doc_count": 0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Category 2",
                            "doc_count": 1217,
                            "pos": {
                                "doc_count": 0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Category 3",
                            "doc_count": 422,
                            "pos": {
                                "doc_count": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

All ingredients have sentiment values. However, the result returns 0.

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Answer (score 0):

So based on your query, you are looking to aggregate on what is within a nested query.

Now, depending on where the sentiment score is, you either have to use the nested location

```
'range' => ['entities.categories.sentiment_score' => [ 'gt' => 0 ]]
```

or then you would have to reverse nest back up the chain

```
    "aggs": {
    "to_ent":  :{
    # EITHER :
    "reverse_nested":{ } # to go to the top level 
    
    "reverse_nested":{ "entities" } # to go to entities level
    }
   }
```

and then you can proceed with the aggs as you wish.

I will update the example if you provide examples.